# List of dojo/on event types?

Tags: javascript, dojo

Can you give a list of recognized strings/event types for dojo/on in Dojo 1.9?

```
query('#someId').on('event', function(){
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/quickstart/events.html

- “click” - the user clicked a node
- “focus” - a node received focus
- “blur” - a node was ‘blurred’, or otherwise lost focus
- “change” - an input value was changed
- “keypress” - fired when the user presses a key that displays
- “keydown” - fired for non-printable keys
- “keyup” - fired when the user releases a key
- “mouseover” - a node was hovered (warning: may fire more than you’d like because of bubbling)
- “mouseout” - a node was un-hovered
- dojo/mouse#enter - a normalized version of onmouseover that wont fire more than you’d like (only on first enter)
- dojo/mouse#leave - a normalized version of onmouseout that wont fire more than you’d like (only once when leaving)
- submit - a form has been submitted

plus the extra

- mousewheel / DOMMouseScroll

Comment: Wow! Whenever I try to find something in Dojo's documentation, I seem to get lost.

Comment: +1 to Zemljoradnik's comment on the Dojo documentation.  It's the worst.

Answer (score 1):

at the basic level, you can use the name of any event that can be fired on the element '#someId' (mousedown, mouseup, click... you'll find a complete list in the HTML specification), and for which you could also register a handler using `element.addEventListener('event', function() {...});`

As the API documentation for `dojo/NodeList.on` states, `on` also "supports event delegation by using selectors as the first argument with the event names as pseudo selectors. For example:

```
dojo.query("#my-list").on("li:click", listener);
```

This will listen for click events within `<li>` elements that are inside the #my-list element.".

Also documented for the on method is the fact that "Because on supports CSS selector syntax, we can use comma-delimited events as well:

```
dojo.query("#my-list").on("li button:mouseover, li:click", listener);
```

"

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. But I thing you're using old syntax, you should leave out "dojo.".

Comment: How about change event in the variable? Say, if there is a change in the value of the variable by programmatic, how will it trigger? What is event emitter?